# QueryDSL: compare array

Tags: mysql, hibernate, kotlin, querydsl

I am having issue with QueryDSL array comparing. The issue is comparing on byte arrays is missing in QueryDSL because ArrayPath extends SimpleExpression which only has methods like eq, ne, in, isNull...

Using Kotlin, Hibernate 5.2, QueryDSL 4.1.4, MySQL 5.7

Having Hibernate ebmeddable object IpAddress

```
@Embeddable
class IpAddress(
        var ipAddressBinary: ByteArray
)
```

which in DB is mapped to type VARBINARY(4) (for IPv4 addresses, IPv6 support planned in future). I store there ip address in binary form which I need for searching in range.

I wanted to create kotlin extension function to support goe and loe functions on my embedded object

So far i came up with this:

```
fun ArrayPath<ByteArray, Byte>.goe(ipBytes: ByteArray): BooleanExpression {
  return Expressions.booleanOperation(Ops.GOE, ConstantImpl.create(ipBytes))
}

fun QIpAddress.goe(ipAddressStr: String): BooleanExpression {
  val ipBytes = MapperUtils.IPv4.normalizedToBytes(ipAddressStr)
  return this.ipAddressBinary.goe(ipBytes)
}
```

but calling

```
query.where(QBlackListRecord.blackListRecord.startAddress.goe(someByteArrayRepresentingIpAddress))
```

results in an exception:

```
 [exec-10]java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index (1) must be less than size (1)
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:310)
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkElementIndex(Preconditions.java:292)
at com.google.common.collect.SingletonImmutableList.get(SingletonImmutableList.java:45)
at com.querydsl.core.types.Template$ByIndex.convert(Template.java:190)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:256)
at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitOperation(JPQLSerializer.java:426)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:231)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:31)
at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:92)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:267)
at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitOperation(JPQLSerializer.java:437)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:231)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:31)
at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83)
at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:92)
at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.serialize(JPQLSerializer.java:220)
at com.querydsl.jpa.JPAQueryBase.serialize(JPAQueryBase.java:60)
at com.querydsl.jpa.JPAQueryBase.serialize(JPAQueryBase.java:50)
at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:98)
at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:94)
at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetch(AbstractJPAQuery.java:201)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QuerydslJpaRepository.findAll(QuerydslJpaRepository.java:164)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.findAll(Unknown Source)
```

I am not sure whether my approach to the matter is correct. Is there any other way to compare byte arrays in QueryDSL which produces simple SQL with simple comparison operators?

All I need is to only produce SQL like this

```
select *
from black_list_record
where start_ip_address_binary >= @binary_value
```

or like this

```
select *
from black_list_record
where start_ip_address_binary >= inet6_aton('10.20.0.1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by function

```
fun ArrayPath<ByteArray, Byte>.goe(ipBytes: ByteArray): BooleanExpression {
  return Expressions.booleanOperation(Ops.GOE, ConstantImpl.create(ipBytes))
}
```

which should look like this

```
fun ArrayPath<ByteArray, Byte>.goe(ipBytes: ByteArray): BooleanExpression {
  return Expressions.booleanOperation(Ops.GOE, this, ConstantImpl.create(ipBytes))
}
```

I did not pass "this" argument for operation GOE which expects two arguments because its template is {0} >= {1}. That is all...

If you dont use Kotlin but Java you can use QueryDSL build-in method delegating - http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.2.1/reference/html_single/#d0e2474